# how to prevent a ball from bouncing only vertically

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a ball bounce off (and also sideways) when it gets into contact with another object. I am having an issue shown in the image below, where the ball rests on the triangle instead of falling off sideways. I tried playing round values for the bounciness and friction, but that didn't solve my issue. How can I solve this issue. I've added the inspector settings on the ball.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it not just perfectly balanced? Try moving it a tiny bit in either direction?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I guess it could be, but it happens too frequently and I wouldn't want this behavior. What range of values would be tiny enough to prevent it from looking unrealistic and when should I change the direction?

Comment: If velocity is 0 or really close to, give it a random push with AddForce.